# Почему _layout.cshtml работает только для главной страницы?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout

Во _ViewStart layout прописан, но действует это только на главную страницу. Если перейти на другую страницу, то там только её собственное содержимое.

Чего не хватает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался: метод Index должен возвращать ActionResult, а не строку